# Drupal 8 page manager and panels contextual filters for views_block

Tags: 8, panels

I'm working with Drupal 8(first project with 8) and trying to build page (via page manager) with taxonomy tid argument.

As a display variant I use panels and inside of panel I put block, generated by views and this views_block have contextual filter.

I haven't found the way for how to attach my contextual filter to views_block plugin from panel or associate context to anywhere.

From debug session I know what panels have my argument as a context. 
But how to pass it to views_block plugin inside of panel?

Thank you for any help and information. I'm ready to digg inside of code(and contribute also, if needed) to solve this.

[image: page manager page]

[image: panels page]

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, since I haven't used Panels for D8 yet. I know in D7 you can pass the argument to the view. But another option you have is to have the view pickup the argument instead. So what exactly do you want to pass to the view? the Node ID?

Comment: I want to pass taxonomy id. In d7 ctools provide modules Views content panes, what extend views pane settings and give option Argument input for source selection.

Comment: `I want to pass taxonomy id` so your node is a taxonomy term?

Comment: My node have attached taxonomy and i want to use filter by them

Comment: Taxonomy reference, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative, you can use Views to pick up the tax term id's

[image]

If your node has multiple tax terms, you need to allow multiple values for your contextual filter

[image]

Comment: It's works for me only like this http://prntscr.com/bqcgho

Comment: I found ctools_views module without appropriate code about Argument input as it was in Drupal 7. May it's no longer useful, perhaps it is in development. In any case at this moment, i'm follow the solution referred above and pick up arguments directly from url.
Thank You.

Comment: @KirilLazur I guess that works too, if my solution doesn't work try unchecking the `load default filter from node page`.

Comment: @No Sssweat your answer works BUT it's not related to the question which is how to pass the view argument to the panel pane!